# Lederboards in PostgreSQL and get 2 next and previous rows

Tags: postgresql

We use Postgresql 14.1

I have a sample data that contains over 50 million records.

base table:

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|  id  | item_id  | battles|  wins  | damage |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|   1  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
|   2  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
|   3  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   4  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   5  |    255   |   35   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |
|   6  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   7  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   8  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.7 |
|   1  |    460   |   18   | 47.35  | 1010.1 |
|   2  |    460   |   27   | 49.18  | 1518.9 |
|   3  |    460   |   16   | 50.78  | 1171.2 |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

We need to get the target row number and 2 next and 2 previous rows as quickly as possible.

Indexed columns:

1. id
2. item_id

Sorting:

1. damage (DESC)
2. wins (DESC)
3. battles (ASC)
4. id (ASC)

At the example, we need to find the row number and +- 2 rows where id = 4 and item_id = 255. The result table should be:

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|  id  | item_id  | battles|  wins  | damage | rank |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|   5  |    255   |   35   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |  2   |
|   3  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |  3   |
|   4  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |  4   |
|   6  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |  5   |
|   7  |    255   |   35   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |  6   |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

How can I do this with Row number windows function?

Is there is any way optimize in query to make it faster because other columns have no indexes?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_top(in_id integer, in_item_id integer) RETURNS TABLE (
        r_id int,
        r_item_id int,
        r_battles int,
        r_wins real,
        r_damage real,
        r_rank bigint,
        r_eff real,
        r_frags int
    )  AS $$
        DECLARE
            center_place bigint;
        BEGIN
            SELECT place INTO center_place FROM
            (SELECT 
                id, item_id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY damage DESC, wins DESC, battles, id) AS place
            FROM 
                public.my_table
            WHERE 
                item_id = in_item_id 
            AND battles >= 20
            ) AS s
            WHERE s.id = in_id;
            
            RETURN QUERY SELECT
                    s.place, pt.id, pt.item_id, pt.battles, pt.wins, pt.damage
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT * FROM 
                        (SELECT
                            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY damage DESC, wins DESC, battles, id) AS place,
                            id, item_id
                        FROM
                            public.my_table
                        WHERE 
                            item_id = in_item_id
                        AND battles >= 20) x
                        WHERE x.place BETWEEN (center_place - 2) AND (center_place + 2)
                    ) s
                JOIN 
                    public.my_table pt
                    ON pt.id = s.id AND pt.item_id = s.item_id;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Use lead() and lag() for getting next and previous rows value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_top(in_id integer, in_item_id integer) RETURNS TABLE (
        r_id int,
        r_item_id int,
        r_battles int,
        r_wins real,
        r_damage real,
        r_rank bigint,
        r_eff real,
        r_frags int
    )  AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT c.*, B.ord -3 AS row_number
  FROM
     ( SELECT array_agg(id) OVER w AS id
            , array_agg(item_id) OVER w AS item_id
         FROM public.my_table
       WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY damage DESC, wins DESC, battles, id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
     ) AS a
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(a.id, a.item_id) WITH ORDINALITY AS b(id, item_id, ord)
 INNER JOIN public.my_table AS c
    ON c.id = b.id
   AND c.item_id = b.item_id
 WHERE a.item_id[3] = in_item_id 
   AND a.id[3] = in_id
 ORDER BY b.ord ;
END ; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6ef4be4d744ce6df5bc04bd2d3094554)

Comment: The solution is interesting, but how to display row_number?

Comment: By adding `b.ord` in the `SELECT` clause, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Now it shows row_number, unfortunately +2 -2 is not displayed, only one row with id = 4

Comment: There was an error in my answer. It is now updated with a link to [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6ef4be4d744ce6df5bc04bd2d3094554) for displaying the result.

Comment: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1a19bb1cbd5ce2f6b01547b11151018a)
Your solution is good, but doesn't show the current row number. I modified your code and I got what I wanted. Can you analyze? and could it be better?

Comment: and this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1db913af0fdb7da953e6882550e5067b) if id = 4

Comment: Your query sounds good, the performance mainly relies on the efficiency of the cte and the number of rows it filters (as low as possible). I added two alternative solutions for the main query in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8e9d5ed46fe13c77fffdcb2a4ed4f3f) that you can compare in your production environment with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` and then select the fastest. The last one seems to be the fatest in the test environment but it must be tested in the production environment to confirm.

Comment: yea, 1 solution is faster than 2, thanks